# asp.net core url redirection based on user login domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-core

I'm working on my first Asp.Net Core MVC and being unfamiliar with the product i've come across an issue i'm hoping someone will be able to help me with.  The environment i'm working in consists of 3 domains.  Two are for company employees and the third is for our customers who access one specific web app.  The project i'm working on is a landing page for several web apps.  Basically when an employee logs into this page they will be presented a the web apps we offer and off they go.  the issue i am running into is with the customer accounts.  When a customer logs in I want to just redirect them to the only web app they have access to.  I have attempted to use the Redirect("url") but i just get a blank page like the redirect never works.  I was looking into the URL Rewriting Middleware but that seems overly complex for what i need to do. This code is coming out of the Controller.

`List WebsiteList = new List();

```
    string NetworkUser = User.Identity.Name;

    //for testing
    NetworkUser = "PUBLICSTUFF\\WHOEVER'";

    if(NetworkUser.Split('\\').First().ToUpper() == "Domain1")
    {
        WebsiteList = _conf.GetSection("WebsitesForDomain1").Get<List<WebsiteViewModel>>();
    }
    else if(NetworkUser.Split('\\').First().ToUpper() == "Domain2")
    {
        WebsiteList = _conf.GetSection("WebsitesForDomain2").Get<List<WebsiteViewModel>>();
    }
    else if(NetworkUser.Split('\\').First().ToUpper() == "PublicStuff")
    {
        //WebsiteList = _conf.GetSection("WebsitesForCustomers").Get<List<WebsiteViewModel>>();              
    }

    return Json(WebsiteList.ToDataSourceResult(request));`
```

I thought I could just return the redirect under the PUBLICSTUFF.

Thank you in advance for any help on this.

Comment: By the way, any string + ToUpper() will never equal "Domain1" or any of the others. You probably should do `.ToUpper() == "DOMAIN1"`.

Comment: i had to remove some company information.  just got lazy typing

Comment: Could you show what you tried to do the redirect? Did you `return Redirect("...");`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  This is what i'm using in this block of code.

 else if(NetworkUser.Split('\\').First().ToUpper() == "PublicStuff")
    {
      return Redirect("www.google.com");
    }